# Laravel 10 Blade @auth not working with ldap-Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, openldap

I am working with LdapRecord in my Laravel Application to authenticate users against an OpenLdap-Server and store the personal details in a DB. The authentication Process works fine without any issues. If I navigate to the next page after completing the authentication the built in function `Auth::check()` returns false though. I checked my session-file and there is nothing in there that looks like the auth information is stored. I also tried the session database but there the user_id field stays empty. I am currently working together with the creator of LdapRecord to fix this issue but maybe someone here can help. All the necessary files are posted in [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/DirectoryTree/LdapRecord-Laravel/issues/608). Thanks for your help